# Attaching meta data to arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a less then ideal situation in which I can not change the signature of a function but need to have it pass additional information in its output for a new feature.

Is this ok to do?

```
q = [ 1 , 2 ,3]
q.meta-data = {additional:'information'}
```

Is this only assigned to q? 
 Does this have any effect on other array objects?
Is there a situation where this would break something or will it continue to function as normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't assign anything to other arrays - as you work with a specific object here, not its prototype.

But yes, it can bite you back in some situations. For example, some other developer might think that it's a smart idea to iterate over that Array stored in `q` with `for-in` loop.

Comment: In regards to the `for-in` loop, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?rq=1

Comment: @Wex Yes, definitely. But some people never learn, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just split the data and the meta-data into two properties?

```
q = {
  data: [1, 2, 3],
  'meta-data': { additional: 'information' }
};
```

Comment: This is a much better idea, assuming he can restructure his data! :-)

Comment: the issue is it takes an arbitrary # of arrays as an argument and iterates over them the implementation is out side of our reach so passing anything additional will wax the whole thing

Answer (score 2):

If you assign a property to `q`, that only affects *just* `q`.  Other arrays will be fine.

The only issue you'd have with this approach is if you use `for..in` to loop over arrays.  As long as you only ever loop over it with a "normal" `for` loop or `.forEach` (which you should be doing anyway), you shouldn't have any issues.

P.S. `q.meta-data` is a syntax error (the `-`).  You need to do `q.metadata` (or `q.meta_data`) or `q['meta-data']`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are great, but you could also convert the array to an "array-like" object.

```
objq = {};
q.forEach(function (elem, idx) {
    objq[idx] = elem;
});
objq.length = q.length;
objq["meta-data"] = {additional: "information"};
```

`objq` does not have array methods, but you can call them:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(objq, function (elem) { console.log(elem); });
```

Comment: @RocketHazmat or you could use `Array.prototype.push.call`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this for a couple reasons. First, you're confounding data and meta-data. How is anyone supposed to retrieve the information they actually care about? Also, you can't use Array operations if you're storing the data in an object.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to create a wrapper for the data. It's a bit safer to attach meta data using symbols.

```
const data = [1, 2, 3];

// A "secret" key to obtain meta data.
const metaKey = Symbol();

data[metaKey] = {additional: 'information'}

// The meta does not appear in for-in anymore.
for (let item in data) {
  console.log(item);
}

// But you still can obtain meta if you have access to the 'metaKey' variable.
console.log(data[metaKey]);
```

The main downside of this approach is that you need to pass the key to the consumer of this meta data.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not like adding properties to arrays since this can have unintended consequences.  I would probably go with adding an addition parameter that acts as an output parameter.  Something like this:

```
function cantChangeReturn(arg1, arg2, optionalOutputArg) {
  // do stuff
  if (optionalOutputArg) {
    optionalOutputArg.extraResult = extraResult;
  }
  return result;
}
```

This way, the extra data does not leak to other parts of the program that do not need it and do not expect it.